# String expression not matched string wide by java regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the following string:

```
÷7%3@x#2$+÷5%3@x#2$-4
```

with the following match:

```
string = string.replaceAll("÷(.+)%(.+)@x#([0-9]+)\\$","÷$1x#$3\\$%$2@");
```

from the above call, I see that: `$1 = (.+) and $2 = (.+) and $3 = ([0-9]+)`

after the call to replaceAll: the string has changed to:
    `÷7%3@x#4$+÷5x#2$%3@-4`

**Notice** that the regex was applied only to `÷5%3@x#2$`  not to `÷7%3@x#2$`

I need the regex to match expression wide.

What could be wrong with the regex?

Comment: Nothing wrong with regex. Your assumption that regex was applied to this `÷5%3@x#2$` and not `÷7%3@x#2$` is not correct. From your regex, `÷` matches the very first `÷` in your string and `$1` is equal to `7%3@x#2$+÷5` and not just `7` as `(.+)` will greedily capture text as much as it can and then match a `%`

Comment: thanks for the idea @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi What I understand is that the regex acts greedy so it consumes all the characters until the last string singleton. That is why it only matches the last occurrence of the string. I've been trying to figure out how to make it non-greedy so it can match all occurrences. I know that I have to use +? to make it non-greedy, but I've been trying different set ups and nothing works. I will use the Pattern class as a work around the problem.

Comment: Did you try replacing every `.+` with `.+?`? That should already do the job. Maybe it is even better to replace each `.+` with `\\d+` since all your examples have only digits in these places.

Comment: yes I've tried that already. And, only digits. I thought about that but what if the numerator has two or more terms, then it will have plus or minus signs. @RolandIllig

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer which is a valid work around as to what am trying to accomplish.
Is not the most elegant solution to the problem, but it works.

In my answer I use the Pattern and Matcher classes to scope out each occurrence of my regex and then replace them as the Pattern and Matcher find each one of them.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("÷.+?%.+?@x#\\d+\\$");
Matcher matchk = patternk.matcher(string);
while(matchk.find()){
String string1 = matchk.group();
String string2 = string1;
string2 = string2.replaceAll("÷(.+)%(.+)@x#(\\d+)\\$","÷$1x#$3\\$%$2@");
string = string.replace(string1,string2);}
```

The result is the formatted string I was looking to get.